# How does IIS and or ASP.NET know which IP the request is coming from?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, security

I am using ASP.NET forms authentication for security and intermittently I have profile overlapping issue. i.e. When I log in as one user it appears as someone else completely at very 'random' time.

Forms authentication is a simple standard implementation with cookie as validation for subsequent requests.So I don't think problem lies there.

While examining IIS logs for the user, I have found that the request is somehow swapped with other active user as it appears to be coming completely from different machine with different ip and user-agent but the same authenticated user.

What I want to know is how ASP.NET or IIS determines which IP the request is coming from?

**EDIT START:**

The output below is actual content of IIS log(event if site name is TestApp1)

```
date    time    cs-method   cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query    cs-username c-ip    sc-status   time-taken
27/08/12    2:32:32 GET /TestApp1/Actions/ViolationsReferralOther/0     178004  10.1.1.24   200 187
27/08/12    2:33:29 GET /TestApp1/Content/datatables/js/datatables-fnSetFilteringDelay.js       178004  10.1.1.39   304 31
```

The first request is from ip address **10.1.1.24** and second one is coming from **10.1.1.39** and both are logged as the same user.

**Authentication code**

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            if (!authTicket.Expired)
            {
                string[] roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(new Char[] { ',' });

                if (roles == null || roles.Length == 0 || (roles.Length == 1 && roles[0] == ""))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                    return;
                }

                GenericPrincipal userPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name), roles);
                HttpContext.Current.User = userPrincipal;
                //hack as per http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SystemThreadingThreadCurrentPrincipalVsSystemWebHttpContextCurrentUserOrWhyFormsAuthenticationCanBeSubtle.aspx
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Current.User = null;
            }

        }            
    }
```

**EDIT END:**

Comment: via *request* header(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is a very late reply**. I should have updated it for the benefit of community a lot early. I am doing it now by following the principle of *better late than never*. The underlying problem was caused by design which I wasn't aware of earlier.

By default, all items are processed by ASP.NET pipeline in IIS 7 and onwards which includes static files such as *js* and *css*. It was fine until the other feature of IIS which, for static files, it uses some smart caching internally for extremely short period of time. However, in my case, it caused the wrong profile assigned to the wrong user.

I excluded the static files from ASP.NET http pipeline (naive way by looking through the file .ext) and the problem went away.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is, "The OS socket layer tells IIS."

The longer answer is that IP addresses are not sufficient to identify individual users, because there may be more than one user sharing the same IP address. Cookies identify the browsing session. If you have an issue where browsing sessions are becoming mixed up, this is likely to be a problem in *your* application code, rather than a problem in IIS or the OS socket layer (both of those are extremely well tested in the real world).

**Update**: You're hacking around with `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal`, which seems dodgy (yes, I read Scott Hanselman's page that you linked to). I wouldn't do that unless you have an *absolutely crystal clear* understanding of why you need to do that and what the implications are. For example, what if the second request is handled by the same thread as the first request, but the second doesn't go through the same authentication block? What is the current principal attached to that thread at that time? Maybe it's still the same as it was for the previous request.

Comment: There may also be more than one IP address for a given user. People usually don't have static IP addresses, and if proxies or VPN is involved, you can see one session jumping IPs.

Comment: @Greg I have updated question to include IIS log and the Authentication logic. I understand it is very unlikely it is infrastructure code where the bug is but still I cannot explain the behaviour at all. Could it be anything to do with Network level?

Comment: @Greg  In fact the hack code was put in there to check whether the hack resolves the issue and apparently it didn't so I can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

IIS simply takes the IP address encoded in the packet it receives from the OS networking layer. Without delving into a bunch of all the networking layer business from the OSI model, ASP.NET is really looking at nothing more than the IP information the underlying webserver provides to it, encoded in a protocol such as HTTP, FTP, et al.